# jqgrid change values of editable cell on change of another cell (dependent columns)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

This is the grid.
[image: grid]

My discount column has an autocomplete which has values coming from another json variable.

This is my json array where the data for discount is coming from.

```
[
  {"id":0.56,"label":"Adams Rite Less 50\/12","value":"Adams Rite Less 50\/12"},
  {"id":0.44,"label":"ASSA Less 44","value":"ASSA Less 44"},
  {"id":0.603,"label":"BARON ACCESSORIES AND STICKS Less 60.3","value":"BARON ACCESSORIES AND STICKS Less 60.3"},
  {"id":0.704,"label":"BARON STD AND CUSTOM DOORS Less 70.4","value":"BARON STD AND CUSTOM DOORS Less 70.4"},
  {"id":0.617,"label":"BARON STD AND CUSTOM FRAMES Less 61.7","value":"BARON STD AND CUSTOM FRAMES Less 61.7"},
  {"id":0.704,"label":"BARON STD PALLET DOORS Less 70.4","value":"BARON STD PALLET DOORS Less 70.4"},
  {"id":0.145,"label":"Bobrick 10\/5","value":"Bobrick 10\/5"},
  {"id":0.6175,"label":"BREMNER HMD","value":"BREMNER HMD"},
  {"id":0.6073,"label":"BREMNER HMF","value":"BREMNER HMF"},
  {"id":0.44,"label":"Eff Eff Less 44","value":"Eff Eff Less 44"}
]
```

What I would like to do is

(1)Upon changing the value of discount the **Cost** column should change according to this formula

```
new Cost = (1-0.145)*List Price Cell's value (in this case 999)
```

The value 0.145 is coming from the id column of the json.

(2)Upon changing the value of discount the **ExtCost** column should change according to this.

```
New Ext Cost = Quantity * new Cost
```

Quantity is the cell on the extreme left.

Here is my grid related code.

```
    var lastsel2;
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        var autocompleteSource;
        $.getJSON("{{ asset('app_dev.php/GetDiscount') }}", function(json){
            autocompleteSource = json;
        });
        var cont;
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: "{{ asset('/app_dev.php/_thrace-datagrid/data/view_PO_details') }}",
            postData: {
                masterGridRowId: {{ editid }}
            },
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['', 'Released', 'Attachments', 'Quantity', 'Received', 'Item #', 'Vendor Item #', 'List Price', 'Discount', 'Cost', 'ExtCost', 'Lead Time', 'System Key', 'PO Item Note', 'PO Required Date', 'Confirm #','Confirm Date', 'VQ #', 'Reference', 'VQ Ref', 'UOM', 'Type', 'Last Update', 'Updated By', 'FSC', 'Door #', 'Queue', 'RTE#'],
            colModel: [
                {
                    name: "POD_UISelected",
                    index: "o.POD_UISelected",
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: 'checkbox',
                    editoptions: {value: "True:False"},
                    formatter: "checkbox",
                    formatoptions: {disabled: false},
                    align: 'center',
                    jsonmap: "cell.0",
                    width: '70'
                },
                {
                    name: "POD_Released",
                    index: "o.POD_Released",
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: 'checkbox',
                    editoptions: {value: "Yes:No"},
                    formatter: "checkbox",
                    formatoptions: {disabled: false},
                    align: 'center',
                    jsonmap: "cell.1",
                    width: '70'
                },
                {
                    name: "I_LinkHasFiles",
                    index: "o.I_LinkHasFiles",
                    editable: false,
                    edittype: 'checkbox',
                    editoptions: {value: "True:False"},
                    formatter: "checkbox",
                    formatoptions: {disabled: true},
                    align: 'center',
                    jsonmap: "cell.2",
                    width: '70'
                },
                {
                    name: "POD_OrderQty",
                    index: "o.POD_OrderQty",
                    editable: true,
                    align: 'center',
                    jsonmap: "cell.3",
                    width: '100'
                },
                {
                    name: "POD_QtyReceived",
                    index: "o.POD_QtyReceived",
                    editable: true,
                    align: 'center',
                    jsonmap: "cell.4",
                    width: '100'
                },
                {name: "POD_ItemNumID #", index: "o.POD_ItemNumID", editable: false, align: 'center', jsonmap: "cell.5"},
                {
                    name: "POD_VendorItemNum",
                    index: "o.POD_VendorItemNum",
                    editable: false,
                    align: 'center',
                    jsonmap: "cell.6"
                },
                {
                    name: "POD_VendorListPrice",
                    index: "o.POD_VendorListPrice",
                    editable: true,
                    align: 'center',
                    formatter: 'currency',
                    formatoptions: {prefix: '$', suffix: '', thousandsSeparator: ','},
                    jsonmap: "cell.7"
                },
                {
                    name: "POD_VendorDiscount",
                    index: "o.POD_VendorDiscount",
                    editable: true,
                    jsonmap: "cell.8",
                    editoptions: {
                       dataInit: function(elem) {
                           var $self = $(this), // save the reference to the grid
                                   $elem = $(elem); // save the reference to <input>
                            $(elem).autocomplete({
                                source: autocompleteSource,
                                select: function (event, ui) {
                                    var $tr = $elem.closest("tr.jqgrow"), newCost, rowid = $tr.attr("id"),
                                            orderQty = parseFloat($tr.find("input[name=POD_OrderQty]").val()),
                                            listPrice = parseFloat($tr.find("input[name=POD_VendorListPrice]").val());
                                    if (ui.item) {
                                        console.log(orderQty);
                                        console.log(listPrice);
                                        newCost = (1 - parseFloat(ui.item.id)) * listPrice;
                                        $self.jqGrid("setRowData", rowid, {
                                            POD_UnitCost: newCost,
                                            POD_ExtCost: orderQty * newCost
                                        });
                                    }
                                },
                                minLength: 0,
                                minChars: 0,
                                autoFill: true,
                                mustMatch: true,
                                matchContains: false,
                                scrollHeight: 220


                            }).on('focus', function(event) {
                                var self = this;
                                $(self).autocomplete( "search", "");
                            });
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: "POD_UnitCost",
                    index: "o.POD_UnitCost",
                    editable: false,
                    align: 'center',
                    formatter: 'currency',
                    formatoptions: {prefix: '$', suffix: '', thousandsSeparator: ','},
                    jsonmap: "cell.9"
                },
                {
                    name: "POD_ExtCost",
                    index: "o.POD_ExtCost",
                    editable: false,
                    align: 'center',
                    formatter: 'currency',
                    formatoptions: {prefix: '$', suffix: '', thousandsSeparator: ','},
                    jsonmap: "cell.10"
                },
                {name: "POD_Leadtime", index: "o.POD_Leadtime", editable: false, jsonmap: "cell.11"},
                {
                    name: "POD_Stocked",
                    index: "o.POD_Stocked",
                    editable: false,
                    edittype: 'checkbox',
                    editoptions: {value: "True:False"},
                    formatter: "checkbox",
                    formatoptions: {disabled: true},
                    align: 'center',
                    jsonmap: "cell.12"
                },
                {name: "POD_Note", index: "o.POD_Note", editable: true, jsonmap: "cell.13"},
                {
                    name: "POD_ReqDate",
                    index: "o.POD_ReqDate",
                    editable: true,
                    jsonmap: "cell.14.date",
                    editoptions:{size:20,
                        dataInit:function(el){
                            $(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
                        },
                        defaultValue: function(){
                            var currentTime = new Date();
                            var month = parseInt(currentTime.getMonth() + 1);
                            month = month <= 9 ? "0"+month : month;
                            var day = currentTime.getDate();
                            day = day <= 9 ? "0"+day : day;
                            var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                            return year+"-"+month + "-"+day;
                        }
                    }
                },
                {name: "POD_ConfrmNum", index: "o.POD_ConfrmNum", editable: true, jsonmap: "cell.15"},
                {
                    name: "POD_PromDate",
                    index: "o.POD_PromDate",
                    editable: true,
                    jsonmap: "cell.16.date",
                    editoptions:{size:20,
                        dataInit:function(el){
                            $(el).datepicker({dateFormat:'yy-mm-dd'});
                        },
                        defaultValue: function(){
                            var currentTime = new Date();
                            var month = parseInt(currentTime.getMonth() + 1);
                            month = month <= 9 ? "0"+month : month;
                            var day = currentTime.getDate();
                            day = day <= 9 ? "0"+day : day;
                            var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
                            return year+"-"+month + "-"+day;
                        }
                    }
                },
                {name: "VQ_PK", index: "o.VQ_PK", editable: false, jsonmap: "cell.17"},
                {name: "pod_reftext", index: "o.pod_reftext", editable: false, jsonmap: "cell.18"},
                {name: "VQ_VRef", index: "o.VQ_VRef", editable: false, jsonmap: "cell.19"},
                {name: "POD_UOM", index: "o.POD_UOM", editable: false, jsonmap: "cell.20"},
                {name: "POD_ItemType", index: "o.POD_ItemType", editable: false, jsonmap: "cell.21"},
                {name: "POD_DateUpdated", index: "o.POD_DateUpdated", editable: false, jsonmap: "cell.22.date"},
                {name: "POD_UpdatedSysUser", index: "o.POD_UpdatedSysUser", editable: false, jsonmap: "cell.23"},
                {name: "I_FSC", index: "o.I_FSC", editable: false, jsonmap: "cell.24"},
                {name: "PjD_NumID", index: "o.PjD_NumID", editable: false, jsonmap: "cell.25"},
                {name: "POD_QueueSourceText", index: "o.POD_QueueSourceText", editable: false, jsonmap: "cell.26"},
                {name: "RTP_PK_E", index: "o.RTP_PK_E", editable: false, jsonmap: "cell.27"}
            ],
            beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                var $target = $(e.target), $td = $target.closest("td"),
                        iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex($td[0]),
                        colModel = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "colModel");
                if (iCol >= 0 && $target.is(":checkbox")) {
                    if(colModel[iCol].name == "POD_UISelected")
                    {
                        $('#list').setSelection(rowid, true);
                        $("#list").jqGrid('saveRow', rowid, { //same rowid value used in 'addRowData' method above
                            succesfunc: function (response) {
                                $('#list').trigger( 'reloadGrid' );
                                return true;
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
                return true;
            },
            onSelectRow: function(id){
                if(id && id!==lastsel2){
                    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow',lastsel2);
                    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow',id,true);
                    lastsel2=id;
                }
            },
            jsonReader: {repeatitems: false},
            height: 400,
            rowNum: 50,
            rowTotal: 1000000,
            autowidth: true,
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: false,
            pager: '#pager',
            shrinkToFit: true,
            sortable: true,
            sortname:"o.POD_ReqDate",
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            //multiselect: true,
            loadonce:false,
            rowList: [50, 100, 500, 1000],
            editurl: "{{ asset('/app_dev.php/_thrace-datagrid/row-action/view_PO_details') }}"
        });
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid',"#pager",{ del:false, add:false, edit:false},
        {editData: {PO_PK: {{ editid }}}},
        {editData: {PO_PK: {{ editid }}}},
        {editData: {PO_PK: {{ editid }}}},
        {multipleSearch:true}
        );
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : true});
        jQuery('#list').jqGrid('gridResize');
        $("#productEdit_V_PK").prop("disabled", true);
    });
```

So far I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967449/jqgrid-how-to-send-read-values-from-different-columns-in-inline-form-edit) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775524/how-to-get-a-jqgrid-cell-value-when-editing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11994181/jqgrid-autocompete-change-another-column)
jqGrid version 4.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't provided a working demo, but I hope that I still understand you correctly.

I think that you want to change the value of not-editable columns `POD_UnitCost` and `POD_ExtCost` on selection of the value in the jQuery UI Autocomplete control in editable `POD_VendorDiscount`. The value of another editable columns `POD_OrderQty` and `POD_VendorListPrice` will be used during calculations. The current code from `select` callback of autocomplete

```
var rowData = $('#list').jqGrid('getRowData', rowid);
cont = rowData.POD_VendorListPrice;
console.log(cont);
rowData.POD_ExtCost = (1-ui.item.id)*cont;
```

is incorrect. The first problem is the usage of `getRowData` to access of columns which are at the moment in **inline editing** mode. It's wrong. `getRowData` will get you HTML fragment from the cells instead of `value` of the corresponding `<input>` element. The second error: you just set `POD_ExtCost` of `rowData` object without any additional actions. It's not changes the value in `POD_ExtCost` column. What you should do instead: you can use `getRowData` and `setRowData` to get/set values of *not editing columns* and you have to get `<input>` elements of editing element and get its `value` to get the current editing value.

I can't test the below code, but the correct way could be for example the following

```
dataInit: function(elem) {
    var $self = $(this), // save the reference to the grid
        $elem = $(elem); // save the reference to <input>
    $elem.autocomplete({
        source: autocompleteSource,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var $tr = $elem.closest("tr.jqgrow"), newCost, rowid = $tr.attr("id"),
                orderQty = parseFloat($tr.find("input[name=POD_OrderQty]").val()),
                listPrice = parseFloat($tr.find("input[name=POD_VendorListPrice]").val());
            if (ui.item) {
                console.log(orderQty);
                console.log(listPrice);
                newCost = (1 - parseFloat(ui.item.id)) * listPrice;
                $self.jqGrid("setRowData", rowid, {
                    POD_UnitCost: newCost,
                    POD_ExtCost: orderQty * newCost
                });
            }
        },
        minLength: 0,
        minChars: 0,
        autoFill: true,
        mustMatch: true,
        matchContains: false,
        scrollHeight: 220
    }).on("focus", function(event) {
        $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
    });
}
```

I should remark that the above code works only for inline editing.

Comment: Thank you Oleg. As always your code works flawlessly. And yes you understand me right. I just thought I would only provide the relevant code and it should be explainable. I will update the code for future users. Thank you so much once again. You're the man.